# select box with duplicate key

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, struts-1

I have struts 1 dropdown in my jsp and having issue with duplicate key. I am getting list of course code from another web service which has duplicate values (Can't able to change the data)

I want to display the courses in my jsp. The problem is after loading the page it is showing last value which has same key.

I am creating a map which has duplicate key but different values

```
Example:

Key:CN values:Computer Networking
Key:CN values:Computer Networking and design
```

I am saving the key in db and after loading the page it is showing second value.

Sorry I didn't try anything, stuck with this point.

It will be helpful anyone tell how to proceed

Because of the duplicate key all the option has been selected which has same key.

In Jquery is there any option to remove the select value of duplicate option

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In order to populate data into a drop down I use both Map and List.

**Sample Form class :-**

```
public class ProgramForm {
      private int id;
      private int name;
      private int courseCode;
      private List<CourseTO> courses; // list of courses in that program
      /* getters and setters*/
}
```

**CourseTO class :-**

```
public class CourseTO {
      private int id;
      private int name;
      private int code;
      /* getters and setters*/
}
```

Now at some part of execution you will be getting a list of courses, copy that data into the CourseTO object and keep adding that object into the List of the Form class. Then instead of a Map bring this List to the drop down.

**JSP code :-**

```
<html:select property="courseCode" name="programForm" styleId="courseId" styleClass="combo">
     <html:option value="">-Select-</html:option>
     <logic:notEmpty name="programForm" property="courses">
           <html:optionsCollection name="programForm"
                                   property="courses"
                                   label="name"
                                   value="code" />
     </logic:notEmpty>         
</html:select>
```

Thus even if you have duplicate course code, there won't be a problem. Hope it helps.

Comment: I hope you want me to create a class and add the list of class into jsp property instead of map. I am not sure if i give it as list how will i get key value pair in jsp

Comment: Where and In Which case do you want this key-value pair, is it in the JSP or in the Java code?

Comment: in jsp select box with key and value pair. i need to send the key to db

Comment: Once a value is selected in the drop down automatically **courseId** (of the Form) will be assigned with the **id** value of selected **CourseTO** in the list. So in the backend code you can iterate the list and retrieve that particular **TO** object ( having id similar to **courseId** ) , which will have other details like name, code etc.

Comment: If i don't have id means what will i do. I am getting those values from another webservice which is giving only code and description and not id and getting the schema from their side only

Comment: Then instead of **id** you assign the **code** attribute of **TO** as the value in **<html:optionsCollection/>** tag. But I'm wondering, if you are saving it into a database you will be having a primary key id.